# Best way to check the availability of a SMTP server with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, email, dns, smtp

Where I'm working there's a lot of mail traffic, almost all of it sent through web applications, and I have to check if an email address exists. I have read a lot of post about it, and all of them send me to the same proccess.

1. First check the syntaxis
2. Then check for the domain DNS and MX records
3. And lastly check for the SMTP server response.

(I have omited Greylist check and Mailbox check)

Well, I have found good resources for the first two steps, but I'm having troubles with the last one. I try some services like the ones provided by [EmailArchitect](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/ex/vb/11.aspx) but with no results, I think thats because of firewalls of my company servers. So I tried some service that provide an alternative through HTTP methods like [verify-mail](http://verify-email.org/) but it just provided DNS check. Finally, I'm now thinking about using [MS SMTP-Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/es-cl/download/details.aspx?id=11393) and execute the process from my code or something, but I think there must be some other solution.

So, my question is if there is any other method that I haven't tried yet, I just want to check SMTP availability, without even worry about exceptions like server down or something. I'll appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the MX record is a URL, check the DNS record for it to make sure it exists. Then try connecting to the smtp server on port 25, something like this:

```
  Using tcp As New TcpClient
    Try
      tcp.Connect(ip, 25)
      ' server found
    Catch ex As Exception
      ' server not found
      End Try
    tcp.Close()
  End Using ' tcpclient
```